# Why does `treemap.nodes` not see the update to my object?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm making a treemap layout with d3.js. My tree has many more leaf nodes than I could possibly visualize, so I want to trim the tree to maintain the percentage of leaf nodes for each branch, but reduce the total number of leaves to some small `n`.

I've successfully implemented a for loop which trims the children of my `data` object in the desired way, but when I call `treemap.nodes(data)`, I get a list with the original number of nodes as the return value rather than the reduced list of nodes with fewer leaves.

Here's a minimal example which reproduces the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>   
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var w = 1280 - 80,
        h = 800 - 180;

    // Declare treemap
    var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
        .round(false)
        .size([w, h])
        .sticky(true)
        .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

    // Load data
    d3.json("demo.json", function(data) {   

        // Trim data 
        var categories = treemap.nodes(data)
            .filter(function(d) { return d.depth==1; });

        n = 10; //This is the maximum number of leaves I want to have
        var total_value = treemap.nodes(data)[0].value;
        for(var vertex of categories) 
        {
            var num_children = vertex.children.length;
            var percentage_screen = num_children / total_value;
            var max_leaves = Math.max(1, Math.floor(n * percentage_screen));
            vertex.children = vertex.children.slice(0,max_leaves)
        }   

        // Here I try to get a list of the leaves       
        var nodes = treemap.nodes(data)
            .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

        // This print statement prints 20, the original number of leaves
        console.log(nodes.length);
        // But if I recursively count the number of leaves, I get the new smaller number, 10
        console.log(recursive_node_counter(data));
    });

    function recursive_node_counter(d){
        if('children' in d){
            var num_child = 0;
            for(child of d.children){
                num_child += recursive_node_counter(child);
            } 
            return num_child;
        } else {
            return 1
        }
    };


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Use together with this json : demo.json

```
{"name": "root", "children": 
    [{"name": "branch_A", "children": 
        [{"name": "A_leaf", "size": 1},
        {"name": "A_leaf", "size": 1},
        {"name": "A_leaf", "size": 1},
        {"name": "A_leaf", "size": 1},
        {"name": "A_leaf", "size": 1}, 
         {"name": "A_leaf", "size": 1}]},
    {"name": "branch_B", "children": 
        [{"name": "B_leaf", "size": 1},
        {"name": "B_leaf", "size": 1},
        {"name": "B_leaf", "size": 1},
        {"name": "B_leaf", "size": 1},
        {"name": "B_leaf", "size": 1},
        {"name": "B_leaf", "size": 1},
        {"name": "B_leaf", "size": 1},
        {"name": "B_leaf", "size": 1},
        {"name": "B_leaf", "size": 1}, 
         {"name": "B_leaf", "size": 1}]},
    {"name": "branch_C", "children": 
        [{"name": "C_leaf", "size": 1},
        {"name": "C_leaf", "size": 1},
        {"name": "C_leaf", "size": 1}, 
         {"name": "C_leaf", "size": 1}]}]}
```

Why does `treemap.nodes(data)` not see the changes to the `data` variable?

Comment: You are not making any changes to the `data` variable. If you change it before doing the data join then those changes will be reflected in the tree structure.

Comment: @cool if I'm not making any changes to the data variable, why does the second print statement print 10?

Comment: Assuming there are no closures is always a bad idea in javascript.  The layout has side effects on the data array so that alone is enough to make me very uncomfortable trying to tunnel back to the data through the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following console statements are more illustrative of the issue:

```
d3.json("./demo.json", function(data) {   

    // Trim data 
    var categories = treemap.nodes(data)
        .filter(function(d) { return d.depth==1; });

    n = 10; //This is the maximum number of leaves I want to have
    var total_value = treemap.nodes(data)[0].value;
    for(var vertex of categories) 
    {
        var num_children = vertex.children.length;
        var percentage_screen = num_children / total_value;
        var max_leaves = Math.max(1, Math.floor(n * percentage_screen));
        vertex.children = vertex.children.slice(0,max_leaves);
    }

    // Here I try to get a list of the leaves       
    console.log(data);
    var nodes = treemap.nodes(data)
        .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });
    console.log(data);
});
```

When we run this code, we get the same unexpected output of

```
20
10
```

Why? If we look at the treemap.nodes(data) call, it becomes clear:

```
function treemap(d) {
  var nodes = stickies || hierarchy(d), root = nodes[0];
  root.x = 0;
  root.y = 0;
  root.dx = size[0];
  root.dy = size[1];
  if (stickies) hierarchy.revalue(root);
  scale([ root ], root.dx * root.dy / root.value);
  (stickies ? stickify : squarify)(root);
  if (sticky) stickies = nodes;
  return nodes;
}

...
...

hierarchy.revalue = function(root) {
  if (value) {
    d3_layout_hierarchyVisitBefore(root, function(node) {
        if (node.children) node.value = 0;
    });
    d3_layout_hierarchyVisitAfter(root, function(node) {
      var parent;
      if (!node.children) node.value = +value.call(hierarchy, node, node.depth) || 0;
      if (parent = node.parent) parent.value += node.value;
    });
  }
  return root;
};
```

On the first call to treemap.nodes(data), stickies is set to the untrimmed data. On the second call to treemap.nodes(data), the function uses the data from the first call through the "stickies" variable. In this same second call, the function then calls hierarchy.revalue(root) on the passed-in trimmed data, which updates the relevant objects.

Comment: In my browser, I need to change the print statement to `console.log(data.value)` to get this behavior. But otherwise, this is a very good explanation of the underlying behavior.

Answer (score 2):

My point is that d3 is meant to be *data driven* so instead of trying to hack the layout object, it's always better to modify the data before joining it to the layout.

One solution: Use a scratchpad version of the data and the treemap to get the benefit of the treemap behaviour to do the trimming, then create a new instance with the modified data...

```
var w = 1280 - 80,
        h = 800 - 180;

// Load data
d3.json("demo.json", function (data) {

    //  make a temp object to use treemap behaviour
    var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
            .sticky(true)
            .value(function (d) { return d.size; }),
    //  cache original data
            tempData = $.extend(true, {}, data),
            //***snap shot 1
    // Trim original data using temp data
            tempNodesData = treemap.nodes(tempData),
            //***snap shot 2
            total_value = tempNodesData[0].value,

            categories = tempNodesData
            .filter(function (d) { return d.depth == 1; }),

            n = 10; //This is the maximum number of leaves I want to have

    categories.forEach(function (vertex, i, categories) {
        var num_children = vertex.children.length,
                percentage_screen = num_children / total_value,
                max_leaves = Math.max(1, Math.floor(n * percentage_screen));

        data.children[i].children = vertex.children.slice(0,max_leaves)
    })

    // re-Declare treemap
    var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
            .round(false)
            .size([w, h])
            .sticky(true)
            .value(function (d) { return d.size; }),

    // Here I try to get a list of the leaves       
            nodes = treemap.nodes(data)
                        .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

    // This print statement prints 20, the original number of leaves
    alert('nodes.length: ' + nodes.length + '\n' + 'recursive_node_counter: ' + recursive_node_counter(data));
    d3.select('body').insert('div', 'script').attr('class', 'logWindow').style({'color': 'red;'})
    .html('nodes.length: ' + nodes.length + '</br>' + 'recursive_node_counter: ' + recursive_node_counter(data));

});

function recursive_node_counter(d){
    if('children' in d){
        var num_child = 0;

        d.children.forEach( function(child){
                num_child += recursive_node_counter(child);
        })
    return num_child;
} else {
                        return 1
}
};
```

In response to the comment below, `tempData` initially looks like this:

[image: ***snap shot 1]

and after the `treemap.nodes(tempData)` statement it looks like this

[image: ***snap shot 2]

If I keep the data in its original form then I don't have to waste time figuring out if the extra properties matter or not (now and in the future!)

Comment: What's the purpose of caching the original data? Just keeping around an unaltered copy?

Comment: Yes, the `.nodes(data)` method has side effects on the `data` argument: it adds extra properties. So the structure of `tempData` is actually changed by the trimming phase. By doing it this way, `data` is modified but it's structure is not changed.